# regexp to find first and last character in a file using grepwin

Tags: regex

I want to remove the first and last character of a file using grepwin. What is the regular expression to find the first and last character with grep?

example

file.txt

```
[{esfdf},{dsdsdds}]
```

The result of the regex

```
{esfdf},{dsdsdds}
```

Comment: Does the file only have one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you can achieve that is using the following regex:

```
(?<!.)^.|.$(?!.)
```

With **Dot matches newline** checked.

The regex above with a *"Replace with:"* like `@` would turn a file like:

```
abc123d3ef1288i
zyz23yo21zozzxcvb
dj231231sosd
```

In:

```
@bc123d3ef1288i
zyz23yo21zozzxcvb
dj231231sos@
```

**To just remove the chars, put nothing as *"Replace with:"*** string and hit <kbd>Replace</kbd>.

<sub>Note:By *"only way"* I mean **"Dot matches newline"** - there is no other way to test EOF (end of file) if not using "dot matches newline". As far as regex and grouping goes, there are virtually unlimited possibilities.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This does exactly what I asked for. I also found that I could find the first character and last character (in my case a "[" and "]") separately by using the following expressions: ^(.*?)\\[ and this \\](?=[^.]*$) respectively. I recommend these for really large files as they took 1 to 2 seconds to execute on a 13 megabyte file while the expression in  the answer took 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way, but in the interest of a quick answer

```
$ awk '{$1=""; $NF=""} 1' FPAT=. OFS= file.txt
{esfdf},{dsdsdds}
```

Comment: I don't think grepwin is a command-line tool (and it's for windows, separate from cygwin).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# Pattern string
^.{1}(.*?).{1}$

# Replace string
$1
```